# Xcode 14 Grid of buttons

Tags: swift, button

I am trying to create a grid of 100 buttons (10x10)

The code below creates them however how can I give them an ID so that I can identify each one and even hide them when I click on one or change its colour etc.?

```
func createButtonGrid(colourArray: Array<String>) {
    
    let spacing = 35
    var xPos = 25
    var yPos = 150
    
    for i in 0...99 {
        print(String(i))
        createButton(xPos:xPos, yPos: yPos, colour: colourArray[i] , title: String(i))
        xPos = xPos + spacing
        
        if i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i == 59 || i == 69 || i == 79 || i == 89 {
            xPos = 25
            yPos = yPos + spacing

        }
    }
}

func createButton(xPos: Int, yPos:Int, colour: String, title: String) {
    let gridButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 30, height: 30))
    gridButton.configuration = plainButtonConfig(colour: colour)
    view.addSubview(gridButton)
}
```

Comment: You could make use of the `tag` property, assign each button a unique id value; alternatively, you could keep them in array or a dictionary

Comment: Tags work, but they are fragile. (If you have multiple views in the view hierarchy with the same tag, you can’t be sure which view `viewWithTag(_:)` will return. Better to keep an array of buttons as you mentioned.

Comment: @madProgrammer how do I then access the tag id? I've seen people mention that you can connect all the buttons to an IBAction but I can't figure out how to connect buttons that don't exist on my storyboard because they are created programmatically. Also if I want to change their colour do these buttons not need to be IBOutlet buttons?

Comment: Is your code that you posted in a view controller?

Comment: `tag` is a property of `UIView`, which `UIButton` extends from (indirectly), so something you'd use it something like `gridButton.tag = some int value`.  When the button is actioned, you can inspect the `tag` property of the source object and from that make determinations of what to do based of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will create the buttons, display them in a 10x10 grid and give them all a tag:

```
func initializeButtons() {
    let spacing = 35
    var xPos = 25
    var yPos = 150

    for i in 0...99 {
                    
        let gridButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 30, height: 30))
        gridButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink
        gridButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        gridButton.tag = i
        gridButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(gridButton)
        
        xPos = xPos + spacing
        if i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i == 59 || i == 69 || i == 79 || i == 89 {
            xPos = 25
            yPos = yPos + spacing
        }
        newButtons.append(gridButton)
    }
    
}
```

Then we can create a function that will have an action when you click the button.

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    
    print(sender.tag)
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refactor your createButton() method to return the button as the function result. Save your buttons into an array. You’re already using a for loop. The button’s index in the array will be the value of `i` for each pass through the loop.

Comment: What would the code for that look like, could you show me an example... how would I then identify a specific button in the array?